# Wordpress SQL LIKE request doesn't work for fields with special symbols

Tags: sql

In WordPress I make SQL-requests to the database but LIKE request doesn't work correctly.

Actial value of `meta_value` field in the database is such string:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:9:"full-time";}
```

if I make this request all works fine:

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'job_bm_job_type' AND meta_value LIKE '%a%' LIMIT 1");
```

But if try to use other text in LIKE part I don't get any results

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'job_bm_job_type' AND meta_value LIKE '%full%' LIMIT 1");
```

Ideally, LIKE request should search through data of all the string. But it seems like it doesn't search inside the content of square brackets `{ }`

What I miss here? How to search through any elements in this field?

Comment: Are you 100% sure the values are correct and there exist results for these queries? Can you try them on the DB directly? I just tested locally and it worked without a problem.

Comment: Sure. The first request gives the value. The second one is not.

Comment: MySQL doesn't care about any of these characters. It should do what you are asking. If you're not getting a result then there's a mistake somewhere. Are these examples the _actual_ query and data you're trying, or examples?

Comment: Also, a taxonomy is a _far_ better option for storing job type. This is considerably slower and less efficient.

Comment: there's no reason to store this as a serialised PHP object, a plain string would work better, and as Jacob said, a term would be significantly easier and more performant. Because you've stored a PHP array containing a single string, rather than just the words `full-time` your task has been made 100x more difficult. I also see that your `prepare` statements only have a single parameter, so nothing is being prepared. The purpose of a call to `$wpdb->prepare` is to safely insert variables into an SQL statement without injection attacks occurring

Comment: Totally agree with you, guys. Unfortunately, I work with a code written by another team a few years ago. I found the problem! I need to escape the quotes to make the request work! I still didn't get why I should do this but it works now!

Comment: @KirMazur Probably because of `prepare`. If you just `$wpdb->query()` it should work without esacping the quotes. Feel free to answer the question yourself (and accept after the time has passed), so future visitors see it instantly

Comment: @kero thanks for hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

Like @Sally-CJ mentioned above, `%f` in the beginning was mistakenly seen as one of supported placeholders for wpdb::prepare() (the other two placeholders are `%s` and `%d`).

So you need to add escaping the quotes `\"`. In my case it's `\"full\"`. With escaping it works perfectly.

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'job_bm_job_type' AND meta_value LIKE '%\"full\"%' LIMIT 1");
```

If you search string starts from letter `a`, `d`, `f` – this finding could help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> What I miss here? How to search through any elements in this field?

Your SQL statements, or the `LIKE '%a%'` and `LIKE '%full%'`, are good.

But the [`wpdb::prepare()`'s documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) says, "*Literal percentage signs (%) in the query string must be written as %%*", hence you should actually use `LIKE '%%a%%'` and `LIKE '%%full%%'`.

But then the documentation also says that:

> Percentage wildcards (for example, to use in LIKE syntax) must be
> passed via a substitution argument containing the complete LIKE
> string, these cannot be inserted directly in the query string. Also
> see
> [wpdb::esc_like()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/esc_like/).

Therefore with `wpdb::prepare()`, you would want to do it like so which is based on the example in the `esc_like()`'s documentation:

<sub>Additionally, instead of hard-coding the table name (`wp_postmeta`), I used `$wpdb->postmeta` — it's a core property and is equivalent to `{$wpdb->prefix}postmeta` used in a double-quoted string `"like this"`.</sub>

```php
$wild = '%';
$find = 'full';
$like = $wild . $wpdb->esc_like( $find ) . $wild; // build the complete LIKE string

// I wrapped the statement for brevity.
$query = $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT meta_value
    FROM $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE meta_key = 'job_bm_job_type'
        AND meta_value LIKE %s
    LIMIT 1
", $like );
```

#### Why exactly `%a%` worked, but `%full%` did not work

- `%full%` starts with `%f` which is one of the supported *placeholders* for `wpdb::prepare()` (the other two placeholders are `%s` and `%d`).

  And because the `prepare()` method detected a placeholder in the query and yet you didn't specify the 2nd parameter for that method, then it returned an empty string and thus no query was made.

  But yes, that `%f` was **mistakenly seen** as a placeholder, which is a reason why `%%` should be used for literal percentage signs in the query.
- `%a%` worked because it does not start with a supported placeholder and thus the `prepare()` method treated the `%` as literal percentage signs. (But MySQL treated them as wildcards)

So in response to your *answer*, adding the `\"` worked because it changed the `%f` to `%\"f` (or just `%"f` when passed to MySQL), which makes it no longer a placeholder.

But then I advise you to use the "complete LIKE string" approach as you could see in my example above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification! Now everything seems clear!

Comment: Glad I could help (and thanks a lot for the +1) :)